# Compare and update target column by excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code . It says match not found .I've shared code and to be uploaded file data as well.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateMasterWorksheet()
    Dim xlApp As Application
    Dim intFF As Integer
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim vntFileName As Variant
    Dim importedData() As Variant
    Dim InputCSVSheet As Worksheet
    Dim importedColumnG As Range
    Dim masterColumnA As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim matchFound As Boolean ' Flag to track if a match is found
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        
    Call SetASheetName
    
    ' Prompt user to select a file
    Set xlApp = Application
    vntFileName = xlApp.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Select File to Import")
    
    ' Check if a file is selected
    If VarType(vntFileName) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "No file selected. Import canceled.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Get selected file name
    strFileName = vntFileName
    
    ' Read data from the file into an array
    intFF = FreeFile
    Open strFileName For Binary Access Read As intFF
    
    ' Read the file content into a byte array
    Dim fileContentBytes() As Byte
    ReDim fileContentBytes(LOF(intFF) - 1)
    Get #intFF, , fileContentBytes
    Close intFF
    
    ' Convert the byte array to a string
    Dim fileContent As String
    fileContent = StrConv(fileContentBytes, vbUnicode)
    
    ' Split the file content into an array of lines
    Dim fileLines() As String
    fileLines = Split(fileContent, vbCrLf)
    
    ' Resize the importedData array to match the number of lines
    ReDim importedData(1 To UBound(fileLines) + 1, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Fill the importedData array with the file lines
    For i = 0 To UBound(fileLines)
        importedData(i + 1, 1) = fileLines(i)
    Next i
    
    ' Set references to the InputCSVSheet and the respective columns
    Set InputCSVSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InputData") ' Replace "InputData" with your actual sheet name
    Set importedColumnG = InputCSVSheet.Range("G14:G" & InputCSVSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row)
    Set masterColumnA = InputCSVSheet.Range("A14:A" & InputCSVSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
    
    ' Loop through the imported data
    For i = LBound(importedData, 1) To UBound(importedData, 1)
        ' Extract the second value from the importedData array
        Dim importedValues() As String
        importedValues = Split(importedData(i, 1), ",")
        
        If UBound(importedValues) >= 1 Then
            Dim importedValue As String
            importedValue = Trim(importedValues(1))
            
            ' Find matching values in column G of the InputCSVSheet
            Dim matchCell As Range
            Set matchCell = importedColumnG.Find(importedValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            
            ' If a match is found, update the corresponding cell in column A with the last value from the imported file
            If Not matchCell Is Nothing Then
                Dim lastValue As String
                lastValue = Trim(importedValues(UBound(importedValues)))
                
                ' Update the corresponding cell in column A with the last value from the imported file
                masterColumnA.Cells(matchCell.row).Value = lastValue
                
                matchFound = True ' Set the flag indicating a match is found
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Check if a match was found or not
    If Not matchFound Then
        MsgBox "No match found in the worksheet.", vbInformation
    End If
    ' Close the opened text file workbook without saving changes
    
    Close intFF
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    MsgBox "Data imported and master worksheet updated successfully.", vbInformation
End Sub

' シート名の設定
Public Sub SetASheetName()
    Set InputCSVSheet = Worksheets("InputData") ' Replace "InputData" with your actual sheet name
End Sub
```

Thank you .

"I want to compare the data in column G of my InputData worksheet with the second value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) in the uploaded CSV file. If there is a match, I want to copy the corresponding value from column 6 of the uploaded file to Column A of InputData. I have included the code and the data from the file to be uploaded. However, when I run the code, it displays 'match not found' as the result."

uploaded data
188215,1,1,Error,,The specified store code is invalid. [01][00188215]
188215,1,1,Error,,The specified code is not registered in the product
188215,1,1,Error,,The product code is not registered in the set product
188220,2,1,Error,,The specified store code is invalid. [01][00188220]

Comment: `LookAt:=xlWhole` is looking for a cell that is an exact match.  This will fail if there are extra spaces.

Comment: Sorry, The uploaded data is CSV file. I just edited that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AmazonErrorImport()
    ' Import text into Excel
    
    ' Variable declaration
    Dim xlApp As Application        ' Application object
    Dim intFF As Integer            ' FreeFile value
    Dim strFileName As String       ' File name to open (full path)
    Dim vntFileName As Variant      ' File name received
    Dim strCurFolder As String      ' Backup of the current folder
    Dim fileToOpen As Variant
    Dim fileFilterPattern As String
    Dim InputCSVSheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Disable screen updating, alerts, events, and set manual calculation mode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Disable confirmation messages
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' Set manual calculation mode
    
    ' Set filter to display text/CSV files
    readFrom = "2"
    
    ' Set sheet name
    Call SetSheetName
    
    ' Header row of the input file
    InputHeadLine = 1
    
    ' Get Application object
    Set xlApp = Application
    
    ' Output message (file selection)
    xlApp.StatusBar = MsgFileSelect
    
    ' Backup the current folder (to change the current folder for file selection)
    strCurFolder = CurDir
    
    ' Set initial folder for file selection
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    ' Receive the file name specified in the "Open File" dialog form
    vntFileName = xlApp.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=cnsFILTER, Title:=cnsTITLE, MultiSelect:=False)
    
    ' Restore the current folder
    ChDir strCurFolder
    
    ' If canceled, exit the subroutine
    If VarType(vntFileName) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub
    strFileName = vntFileName
    
    ' Clear header row count
    InputHeadCnt = 0
    
    ' Clear read count
    InputCnt = 0
    
    ' Clear order count
    EdtRecCnt = 0
    
    ' Get FreeFile value
    intFF = FreeFile
    
    ' Open the specified file (in input mode)
    Open strFileName For Input As intFF
    
    ' Add to the existing worksheet
    Set InputCSVSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InputData")
    
    ' Copy the data to the import worksheet
    Dim ImportedWorkbook As Workbook
    Set ImportedWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    Dim importRange As Range
    Dim importValues As Variant
    Dim importValue As String
    Dim inputColumnG As Range
    Dim inputColumnGValues As Variant
    Dim completed As Boolean
    
    completed = False
    
    With ImportedWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set importRange = .UsedRange
        importValues = importRange.Value
    End With
    
    Set workingRange = InputCSVSheet.Range("A3")
    inputColumnGValues = InputCSVSheet.Columns("G").Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = UBound(importValues, 1)
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        importValue = Trim(importValues(i, 2))
        
        Set inputColumnG = InputCSVSheet.Columns("G").Find(importValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not inputColumnG Is Nothing Then ' Value matches
            If InputCSVSheet.Range("A" & inputColumnG.Row).Value = "" Then
                InputCSVSheet.Range("A" & inputColumnG.Row).Value = importValues(i, 6)
            Else
                InputCSVSheet.Range("A" & inputColumnG.Row).Value = InputCSVSheet.Range("A" & inputColumnG.Row).Value & "  " & importValues(i, 6)
            End If
            
            completed = True ' Completion flag
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Close the opened text file workbook without saving if there were changes
    ImportedWorkbook.Close False
    
    ' Resume screen updating, alerts, events, and automatic calculation mode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' Enable confirmation messages
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Enable events
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' Set automatic calculation mode
    
    ' Completion message
    If completed Then
        MsgBox "File upload completed."
    Else
        MsgBox "File upload failed."
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Solved
This code is running.
Thanks everyone

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**